# Merge two columns in Apex report

Tags: html, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

i have two columns in my report : amount and currency
instead of showing each one in a separate column i wanna show the currency next to the amount in one column
i know i can do it in SQL with :

```
select amount||currency_id from my_table
```

or (since currency column is a shared component)

```
select amount||currency from my_table, currency_table
where my_table.currency_id = currency_table.currency_id
```

so is there a way to merge them or SQL code is the only way?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write the SQL is:

```
select t.amount || c.currency
from my_table t join
     currency_table c
     on t.currency_id = c.currency_id;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Qualify column references in your queries, so you know where the columns come from.
- Use table aliases, so the query is easier to write and read.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge them at the Oracle APEX rendering level. In order to achieve this, you would select your 2 columns amount and currency independently (in the SQL query source for the report), and then chose 'Column Formatting' = Html expression for one of the columns, the amount for example. In here you can write custom HTML and refer to any columns in the report with #column_nsme# syntax

See 9.6.3.4 here https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/managing-interactive-report-column-attributes.htm#HTMDB-GUID-D3275F83-328B-477F-AA35-8BC7DCD3DC1F

So your could have simply "#AMOUNT# #CURRENCY#"

The second column currency you choose not to display it (don't remember the attribute off the top of my head)

In this way you can keep presentation separate from the data layer / query, so if you want to tweak how things look in the future you just change the html text or the styling, and don't touch the query